# How to perform runtime type checking in Dart?

Tags: dynamic, dart, instanceof, dart-mirrors

Dart specification states:

> Reified type information reflects the types of objects at runtime and may always be queried by dynamic typechecking constructs (the
>   analogs of instanceOf, casts, typecase etc. in other languages).

Sounds great, but there is no `instanceof`-like operator. So how do we perform runtime type-checking in Dart? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

The instanceof-operator is called `is` in Dart. The spec isn't exactly friendly to a casual reader, so the best description right now seems to be http://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/.

Here's an example:

```dart
class Foo { }

main() {
  var foo = new Foo();
  if (foo is Foo) {
    print("it's a foo!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is no mention of `is` operator at all in the specification. It's better to refere to the grammar file in Dart sources: https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/trunk/dart/language/grammar/Dart.g

Comment: @Idolon, the `is` operator is defined on page 59 of the spec, section 10.30 'Type test'

Comment: `is` and `is!` can be found in the [Operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators) section of the Dart language tour.

Comment: new syntax is `getTypeName(dynamic obj) => obj.runtimeType;`

Comment: Is there a way to use the runtimeType to check whether a particular named constructor was used?

Comment: The Dart Language Tour has sections on equality operators: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#equality-and-relational-operators and type operators: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Comment: How to use this operator to check Maps because maps can have several types like <Type, type> etc?

Comment: Make sure you don't combine the two different methods here and end up with `foo.runtimeType is String` that screwed me up for a while.

Answer (score 78):

Dart `Object` type has a `runtimeType` instance member (source is from `dart-sdk` v1.14, don't know if it was available earlier)

```
class Object {
  //...
  external Type get runtimeType;
}
```

Usage:

```
Object o = 'foo';
assert(o.runtimeType == String);
```

Comment: RuntimeType is only for debugging purposes and the application code shouldn't depend on it. It can be overridden by classes to return fake values and probably returns unusable values when transpiled to JS

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I'm pretty new to Dart, and I agree that `runtimeType` may be overriden by classes, although I can't think of a reason why they would. (external code can't set the value sinse it's a getter) Personally, I would stick to `is` and reflection.

Comment: It's fine this is mentioned here. It's not very obvious that `runtimeType` has these limitations.

Comment: Gunter, is it still the case that `runtimeType` should only be used for debugging purposes? I ask because there isn't any mention of this in the docs for Object, or elsewhere (that I could find).

Comment: @MattC yes, I was using `runtimeType` to generate HTML classes on the fly, it works with development build, but fails with release build, e.g. in my case result is `minified:ed` instead of `column`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer comment is no longer true in Dart 2. It should be fine to use it now.

Comment: @vovahost I'm mot aware of any related changes. Why do you think my comment is obdolete?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm not expert on Dart 2 differences. I commented based on this discussion https://ibb.co/WcVJzhz https://ibb.co/zmgq168 Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm not sure why he thinks it's ok in Dart 2. Perhaps I missed something.

Comment: "is" repects class hierarchy.  Comparing runtimeType must have a precise equality.  Therefore, please use "is".

Answer (score 22):

As others have mentioned, Dart's `is` operator is the equivalent of Javascript's [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator. However, I haven't found a direct analogue of the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator in Dart.

Thankfully the [dart:mirrors reflection API](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-mirrors) has recently been added to the SDK, and is now available for download in the [latest Editor+SDK package](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/editor/). Here's a short demo:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors'; 

getTypeName(dynamic obj) {
  return reflect(obj).type.reflectedType.toString();
}

void main() {
  var val = "\"Dart is dynamically typed (with optional type annotations.)\"";
  if (val is String) {
    print("The value is a String, but I needed "
        "to check with an explicit condition.");
  }
  var typeName = getTypeName(val);
  print("\nThe mirrored type of the value is $typeName.");
}
```

Comment: [Is Dart a statically typed language?](https://dart.dev/faq#q-is-dart-a-statically-typed-language)

Comment: it is good solution but, we have error:

``Unsupported operation: dart:mirrors is no longer supported for web apps``

Comment: @Lii This answer was written for Ecma TC52. See https://dart.dev/faq

Comment: Be aware that Flutter, if you're using that, disables reflection (because it breaks tree shaking).

Answer (score 21):

Simply use `.runtimeType` on the property like below,

```
print(unknownDataTypeProperty.runtimeType)
```

Answer (score 20):

There are two operators for type testing: `E is T` tests for E an instance of type T while `E is! T` tests for E *not* an instance of type T.

Note that `E is Object` is always true, and `null is T` is always false unless `T===Object`.

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by by `T===Object`? Dart doesn't have the triple equals operator, but you chose to use it rather than double equals, so I assume the difference has significance.

Comment: @MattC That was written more than 7 years ago! I think what I meant was `null is Object` would be true but `null is T` false for any other type T. tbh though I haven't been near Dart for many years now so can't be certain.

Comment: You save my day man! With this: 

`var isAuthFailure = Failure is! AuthenticationFailure;`

Answer (score 20):

Exact type matching is done via `runtimeType` property. Checking if an instance or any of its parent types (in the inheritance chain) is of the given type is done via `is` operator:

```
class xxx {}

class yyy extends xxx {}

void main() {
  var y = yyy();
  
  print(y is xxx);
  print(y.runtimeType == xxx);
}
```

Returns:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 15):

Just to clarify a bit the difference between `is` and `runtimeType`. As someone said already (and this was tested with Dart V2+) the following code:

```dart
class Foo {
  @override
  Type get runtimeType => String;
}
main() {
  var foo = Foo();
  if (foo is Foo) {
    print("it's a foo!");
  }
  print("type is ${foo.runtimeType}");
  
}
```

will output:

```
it's a foo! 
type is String
```

Which is wrong.
Now, I can't see the reason why one should do such a thing...

Answer (score 3):

`if(value is int )` Returns true if the type of the value is int,
else `if(value is! int )`

Answer (score 2):

`T`  is The type

```
   print( T.runtimeType)
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To check the type of a variable use ***runtimeType***

```
void main() {
  int a = 10;
  print(a.runtimeType);
}
```

to check whether the type of a variable is the same as your expected use ***is*** or ***runtimeType***

```
void main() {
  int a = 10;
  print(a.runtimeType == int); // true
  //or
  print(a is int); // true
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

- `.runtimeType` property does an exact type match.
- `is` keyword matches on parent class types and class extension types

```
    class Aaa {}

    class Bbb extends Aaa {}
    
    void main() {
      var x = Bbb();
      
      print(x is Aaa);                  // true
      print(x is Bbb);                  // true
      print(x.runtimeType == Aaa);      // false
      print(x.runtimeType == Bbb);      // true
      print(x.runtimeType);             // Bbb
      print(x.runtimeType.runtimeType); // _Type
      print(x.runtimeType.toString());  // Bbb
    }
```