# Flutter: How to check if an object is an instance of a class(A stateful or stateless widget)

Tags: flutter

I'm an Android developer trying to learn flutter. I'm stuck in checking whether an object is an instance of a class (A stateful or stateless widget) or not.

In Java we use like

```
if (object instanceOf MyClass) {
   // object is an instance of MyClass
} else {
   //  object is not an instance of MyClass
}
```

But i don't know how to do it in flutter.

So far I've tried,

```
if (object is MyClass) {
   // object is an instance of MyClass
} else {
   //  object is not an instance of MyClass
}
```

but this is always false.

I've seen another possible way of doing it `new isInstanceOf<MyClass>()` which is available in `package:matcher/matcher.dart` package but i don't know how to implement it properly.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: object is MyClass looks correct. How did you create your object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform runtime type checking in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715948/how-to-perform-runtime-type-checking-in-dart)

Comment: Mine is not just a class its also a stateful widget. I've corrected my question. Sorry for that misleading question.

Comment: I'm creating the object with `new MainPage()`

Answer (score 32):

**is** works perfect with Widget classes.
For example I have a widget

```
class AccountCreationPage extends StatefulWidget {...}
```

Then I can check that my variable of type Widget is of AccountCreationPage class (gives true, if it is really this class):

```
_loginPage is AccountCreationPage ? 'Creation' : ""
```

Answer (score 13):

Try using debugging your object's class:

```
debugprint("$<object name>");
```

And then manually match the class types.

That means that you will find out the needed class for the `is` operator.

```
object is <object's class>
```

Comment: This is not working for me. `debugprint("$_page")` prints `MainPage` and `if (_page is MainPage)` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use equals operator

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is MyApp;
  }
}
```

Then check as following

```dart
if (object == MyApp)
```

Comment: it is true, when I try `T is ABloc`, it doesn't work but `T == ABloc` does. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Flutter Dart-js-util-library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-js_util/instanceof.html) you can check as below:

```
if (instanceOf(object, MyClass)) {
   print ('instance of MyClass');
} else {
   print('unknown instance');
}
```

**Note** This is web only library, won't work on iOS or Android