# How to check if a type parameter is a specific type in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have some Dart code where I want to implement special behaviour in case a generic type's parameter is a `Stream`.

It's something like this:

```
class MyType<A> {
    A doit() {
        if (A is Stream) // doesn't work!
        else something-else;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: don't know dart but is this the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715948/how-to-perform-runtime-type-checking-in-dart    looks like you're asking if type A is type Stream to me

Comment: That's a different question. I am asking how to check the type a type parameter represents, not the type of a value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `A is Stream` because `A` is actually a `Type` instance. However you can use `if (A == Stream)` or with a dummy instance `if (new Stream() is A)`.

Comment: Using `==` does not work because `Stream` is not equal to `Stream<SomeType>`... I cannot create a dummy instance for the same reason: I would need to know the type parameter of the `Stream` which I can't see how to do.

Comment: What I needed is equivalent to Java's `Stream.class.isAssignableFrom(A)` (if Java had reified generics).

Answer (score 0):

You could normally use `A == Stream`, but you said in your case, you have `Stream<SomeType>`.

If type will always be `Stream`, you can create a dummy instance using the type parameter you have:

```dart
class MyType<A> {
  A doit() {
    final instance = Stream<A>();

    if (instance is Stream<SomeType>) { // ... }
    else if (instance is Stream<OtherType>) { // ... }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```dart
<A>[] is List<Stream>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).