# Error: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> while fetching JSON

Tags: json, flutter

I'm building an events app using Flutter that fetch data from an Rails api and show its details.
I got the same error as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854891/error-listdynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-mapstring-dynamic), and already tried the answer from "kapsid", but can't solve yet.

---

My model class (evento.dart). Basically it represents a Larger event with multiple small events in it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';    

class Evento {
  int id;
  String titulo, descricao, inicio, fim, dataFimInscricao;
  List<Evento> children;

  Evento(
      {this.id,
      this.titulo,
      this.descricao,
      this.inicio,
      this.fim,
      this.dataFimInscricao,
      this.children});

  factory Evento.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['children'] as List;
    List<Evento> childrenList = list.map((c) => Evento.fromJson(c)).toList();

    return new Evento(
      id: json['id'],
      titulo: json['titulo'],
      descricao: json['descricao'],
      inicio: json['inicio'],
      fim: json['fim'],
      dataFimInscricao: json['data_fim_inscricao'],
      children: childrenList
    );
  }
```

The main.dart to list various similar large events

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:eventos_app/detalhesEvento.dart';
import 'package:eventos_app/model/evento.dart';
import 'package:eventos_app/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Evento> futureEvento;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureEvento = fetchEvento();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: futureEvento,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              var eventos = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: eventos.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ListTile(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      leading: Icon(
                        Icons.local_florist,
                        size: 35,
                      ),
                      title: Text(eventos[index]['titulo']),
                      subtitle: Text(
                          'Data: ${parseDate(eventos[index]['inicio'])}\n${eventos[index]['endereco']}'),
                      onTap: () {
                        var evento = Evento.fromJson(eventos[index]);
                        print(evento.titulo);
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    DetalhesEvento(evento: evento)));

                        // Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        //   content: Text('${event.title} tapped!'),
                        //   duration: new Duration(seconds: 1)
                        // ));
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } // else
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Evento> fetchEvento() async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d8142');

  print('----------------------------------------\n');
  print(response.body);
  print('\n----------------------------------------');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
//    return Evento.fromJson2(json.decode(response.body));
    return Evento.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load events');
  }
}
```

And this is the sample JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "MAIN EVENT",
    "descricao": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In elementum metus erat. Morbi sit amet pellentesque elit. Sed at gravida nisi. In in diam in mi gravida iaculis. Phasellus ac leo vel arcu faucibus porta at nec elit. Proin imperdiet leo congue, mattis nunc non, laoreet turpis. Morbi sed faucibus lorem.",
    "inicio": "2020-03-13T10:00:00.000-03:00",
    "fim": "2020-03-31T23:59:00.000-03:00",
    "data_fim_inscricao": "2020-03-31T23:59:00.000-03:00",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "titulo": "SECONDARY EVENT AAA",
        "descricao": "AAAAA",
        "inicio": "2020-03-24T08:00:00.000-03:00",
        "fim": "2020-03-25T18:00:00.000-03:00",
        "data_fim_inscricao": "2020-03-23T08:00:00.000-03:00",
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "titulo": "SECONDARY EVENT BBB",
        "descricao": "BBBBB",
        "inicio": "2020-03-13T23:59:00.000-03:00",
        "fim": "2020-03-25T23:59:00.000-03:00",
        "data_fim_inscricao": "2020-03-13T23:59:00.000-03:00",
        "children": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "titulo": "SECONDARY EVENT CCC",
        "descricao": "CCCCC",
        "inicio": "2020-03-14T10:00:00.000-03:00",
        "fim": "2020-03-16T23:59:00.000-03:00",
        "data_fim_inscricao": "2020-03-16T23:59:00.000-03:00",
        "children": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: this looks like a mismatch of datatypes between what the api returns and where you want to put it.  I think that user @Dhiraj Sharma had a better idea on how to approach the problem.  Add good way to start to troubleshoot this is by adding .runtimetype to your variables. (you can see some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715948/how-to-perform-runtime-type-checking-in-dart) Believe me, this isn't going to be the last time you see this error message.  It's common when coding in a strongly typed language.  What do you see when you have print(response.runtimetype)?

Comment: @WilliamTerrill
print(response.runtimeType)  =  Response;    
print(response.body.runtimeType)  =  String;  
print(jsonDecode(response.body).runtimeType)  =  List<dynamic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a mismatch between the data that you've received from how the data is expected to be received. Specifically, you're trying to pass response.body with is of type `List<dynamic>` to a function that is looking for `Map<String, dynamic>`

I can't run your code, but it looks like the problem is happening on this line in FetchEvento:

```
return Evento.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)); // <-- you're passing List<dynamic>
```

because you are passing response.body with type `List<dynamic>` to `Evento.fromJson()` which is expecting a variable of type `Map<String,dynamic>`

```
factory Evento.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {  //<-- you defined json as Map<String,dynamic>
```

Because dart is a strongly typed language, they have to be defined as the same type.

The easiest solution would either be one of three things: 
1. The easiest would be to change the type of variable received to:

```
factory Evento.fromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
```

2. However, that might break something else. (why else would it be defined as `Map<String, dynamic>`?)  Therefore, the second thing to do would be to manipulate response.body from a `List<dynamic>` to `Map<String,dynamic>`inside `fetchEvento()` prior to sending it to `Evento.fromJson()` by doing something similar to:

```
var map1 = Map.fromIterable(response.body, key: (e) => e.name, value: (e) => e.value);
```

(you can read more about that here: https://bezkoder.com/dart-convert-list-map/)

I hope that it's option 1!

Comment: Did that help? are you able to change the parameter to List<dynamic>?

Comment: not yet ... i'm almost having a stroke, but i think i'm closer to solve lol. I will update my question and the new error.

Comment: Finally got it!! That's exactly what you said, my json returned a list of objects, so I needed to handle this BEFORE mapping my keys, as you suggested with "option 2". I learned a lot from your answer, thanks for the guidance!

Comment: sure! You never know… It might help the next guy!