# How can i check whether variable holds double value or null value in dart?

Tags: dart

**For example i have declared  two varaibles**

```
var latitude;
var longitude;
```

**Now i want to check whether latitude or longitude or both hold double value or they are null **

Comment: You should not declare variables using `var` and not give the variable a value right away. The reason is that the determined type for these variables ends up being `dynamic` since Dart cannot know what type they are going to get.

Answer (score 3):

First, stop making your own life harder than it has to be, use the proper types:

```
double? latitude;
double? longitude;

if(latitude == null)
{
    // ...
}

if(longitude == null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a value is null, you can simply do:

```
if (latitude === null) {
}
```

To check runtime types (e.g. checking if a variable is a double), one can use:

```
latitude.runtimeType
```

See [How to perform runtime type checking in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715948/how-to-perform-runtime-type-checking-in-dart)

Comment: Don't use `runtimeType` for that. Use instead `if (latitude is double)`. `runtimeType` can lead you into some nasty problems and should be used rarely.