# Flutter: How to identify if a widget is Container() / ListTile()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-container

if i have a listview builder which is comprised of empty Container() and ListTile() in random order, how can i identify which widget appeared at particular index ?

Comment: This question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715948/how-to-perform-runtime-type-checking-in-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print(widget.runtimeType);` to determine the type of a widget.